# Devolver el cursor hecho por una consulta dinámica en PL/SQL

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Estoy haciendo un SP donde declaro como parámetro `(..., IO_CURSOR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)` y dentro del SP hago unos ciclos donde se va formando la L_QUERY; las últimas líneas se componen de

```sql
OPEN IO_CURSOR FOR L_QUERY USING L_ID_CONTRATO;

END; --ACA TERMINA EL SP
```

Me deja compilar el paquete pero cuando lo ejecuto me tira:

> ORA-00933: comando SQL no terminado correctamente
> ORA-06512: en "VIALIDAD.PCK_PLANINVERSION", línea 1647
> ORA-06512: en línea 7

Si hago dbms output a la L_QUERY y la ejecuto aparte sí funciona sin hacerle ninguna modificación.

¿Cómo se puede solucionar?

Intenté agregar `return io_cursor` pero no me deja porque es función.

Comment: qué ocurre si en L_QUERY ponés una consulta super simple, digamos, `select 1 uno from dual`?

Comment: se imprime el 1, osea funciona bien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

despues de haberme partido la cabeza buscando el problema del SP, llegué al problema que fue que mi consulta dinámica terminaba con ; y por eso me funcionaba cuando la ejecutaba a parte, pero para la consulta dinámica no debe terminar con punto y coma.

Comment: Perfecto! Acuérdate de marcar tu pregunta como resuelta

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta. Esto hará que el bot _Comunidad_ no relance la pregunta al inicio una y otra vez cada cierto tiempo.